# How to identify the first three digits in a numeric variable

Tags: stata

I have a panel dataset and the first three digits of individual ID contains some regional information. i.e. the same first three digits indicate the individual belongs to the same group.

I want to extract the three digits alone to create a regional dummy but I have no idea how to do so. There were some references online but they were about extracting information from string variables but mine was `long %10.0g` . Also, from what I have found online, the first two digits can be extracted with `floor()`, but I don't know how to deal with three digits.

The ID series I have contains 7 number each, and I only need the first 3 numbers.

**Update**

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input long schid
3025408
3304332
3305402
3414787
3414790
3514026
8004138
8154069
8314181
8715408
8734501
8914107
8934501
8944425
9084153
9084163
9084170
9195410
9284094
9334451
end
```

This is the randomly picked ID example, and I only need the first three digits.

Comment: You should always be able to show real(istic) example data, even if you are clueless about code.

Comment: @NickCox I have updated the answer. I am not sure if it is what you meant.

Comment: Yes; that would have helped. In this case it was easy enough to produce a sandbox for play, but often good answers to questions depend crucially on seeing the data, so the principle is important for any future questions, whether here on SO or elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`floor()` is still a good answer in your case. Consider

```
. clear

. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. gen long exampleid = 123456789

. gen first3 = floor(exampleid/1e6)
```

Here in `1e6` the `e` indicates a power of 10; it is not the number e = 2.71828 to 5 d.p.. So `1e6` is 10 to the power 6, or 1 million = 1,000,000.

You can also do this by string manipulation, but I don't recommend this method. It's much easier to get wrong, say by omitting a format argument.

```
. gen First3 = real(substr(string(exampleid, "%9.0f"), 1, 3))
```

To show that both methods work:

```
. list 

     +-----------------------------+
     | exampleid   first3   First3 |
     |-----------------------------|
  1. | 123456789      123      123 |
     +-----------------------------+
```